# Decode a string which contains the encoded patten

Tags: string, algorithm, encoding, decoding

Consider following problem:

```
string s = "fffffssss"
```

The encoded string will be `5xf4xs` but what if there are encoded pattern in `s`? For example `s="5xfxxx"`, what shall I do in encoder to avoid ambiguity? provided that the encoded string must be shorter than origin one.

Answer (score 0):

To encode `5xfxxx`, you will obtain `1x51xx1xf3xx`, which does not have any ambiguity (there is only one way to decode such a string, you have to consider triplets). Things can get a bit trickier when you have more than 10 similar characters in a row in your string, but there will still not be any ambiguity.

As for the constraint that the encoded string must be shorter than the origin one, there is no such guarantee. `x` will be encoded as `1xx` which is three times longer. This is your worst case scenario: a result 3 times longer than the original one.

If you are looking for ways to compress a string, I suggest you have a look at [Huffman's coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), which is simple and efficient (it is almost optimal with regards to compression, and runs in linear time). You will have to consider binary strings though.

Comment: I can encode it as `51xxfxxx`, which is only 2 characters longer than the input, if we assume that `x` is only decoded special if preceded by a digit.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep the same encoding scheme, where `dxc` results in *d* (a digit) repetitions of *c* (a character), then you can simply encode inputs such as `5xy` with `5`**`1xx`**`y`. Yes, you will pay a price of 2 extra characters whenever you find a digit followed by an `x` in the input.

There is no (non-lossy) encoding which guarantees that the output will always be shorter than the input. Even stronger: there is no encoding that guarantees that it will always create outputs of either the input's length or shorter, except for not encoding anything at all (which will always yield output length equal to its input). All compression schemes rely on there being redundancy in the input, and will not compress anything at all with truly random data. Therefore, whether a compression scheme is good or not depends on whether it can exploit the redundancy in its expected inputs well or not.

A simple scheme to guarantee that you *never* pay a penalty of more than 1 character is to use an initial token to indicate whether the string is encoded or not. For example, say that the 1st character is `0` if no encoding was performed, and `1` if it is encoded. Then,

```
encode("1x2x3x4x") = "01x2x3x4x"; // only 1 character longer than input
encode("1x2x3x4x") = "111xx21xx31xx41xx"; // not so good: 8 chars longer
```

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that "aaaaaaaaaa" would be encoded as "10xa", meaning that the "multiplier" *n* in the produced *nxc* pattern could consist of more than one digit.

One idea is to introduce a special escape character, like for example the hash "#". Whenever the input has a series of digits, let the encoding algorithm append a hash after such a sequence. That way it can never be confused with the *nxc* pattern. In the decoding you would remove such a trailing hash.

Whenever the input has itself a hash, then escape it in the same way as above: append an additional hash right after it.

So in your example, `5xfxxx` would be encoded as `5#xf3xx`. However, if a series of digits can be written in the *nxc* notation, then the hash will not be used. So `999x1` would be encoded as `3x91`, while `122x1` would be encoded as `122#x1`. 
Similarly, `###` would be encoded as `3x#`, not escaping any hash. So applying the *nxc* pattern would always get priority over escaping.

Here is a little JavaScript implementation of these encode/decode functions, relying heavily on [regular expression-based replacements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). You can play with it:

```js
function encode(s) {
    // If a character occurs 3 or more times in sequence, encode that sequence;
    // Otherwise, append a hash after any sequence of digits, 
    //            and after each individual hash:
    return s.replace(/(.)\1\1+|\d+|#/g, (m, ch) => 
        ch ? m.length + "x" + ch : m + "#");
}

function decode(s) {
    // If a nxc sequence is found, decode it
    // Otherwise, if a character is followed by a hash, remove the hash
    return s.replace(/(\d+)x(.)|(.)#/g, (m, times, ch, esc) => 
        times ? ch.repeat(+times) : esc);
}

// I/O management of this snippet:
let elemInput = document.querySelector("#input");
let elemEncoded = document.querySelector("#encoded");
let elemDecoded = document.querySelector("#decoded");
let elemCheck = document.querySelector("#check");
elemInput.addEventListener("input", function () { // Whenever input changes:
    let encoded = encode(this.value); // Encode...
    let decoded = decode(encoded); // ...and decode the encoded string again
    elemEncoded.textContent = encoded;
    elemDecoded.textContent = decoded;
    // Check whether the decoded string is equal to the input:
    elemCheck.textContent = this.value == decoded ? "OK" : "Difference!";
});
```

```html
Input: <input id="input">
<div>Encoded: <span id="encoded"></span></div>
<div>Decoded: <span id="decoded"></span></div>
<div>Check: <span id="check"></span></div>
```

Obviously this means some inputs will have an encoded equivalent that is longer than the original input. Unless you use an algorithm that always encodes to a string that is just as long as the input, or unless the output may contain something that can never appear in the input, it is not possible to prevent cases where the output is longer than the input.

NB: I removed the `s` flag from the regexes as not all browsers support it yet, but it should be there if newlines can occur in your input.